# Как правильно написать триггер в pl/sql?

Tags: oracle, plsql, триггер

Условие: необходимо написать триггер в pl/sql, который будет заносить в таблицу B все изменения, которые будут происходить в таблице A. То есть, если я буду применять операции INSERT, UPDATE или DELETE к таблице A, то это сразу будет записано в таблицу B. В эту таблицу будет заноситься информация о том, какое по счёту это изменение, имя пользователя, который это сделал и действие, которое пользователь сделал. Вот мой триггер:

```
create or replace TRIGGER insert_trig
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON a
BEGIN 
IF INSERTING THEN
INSERT INTO b(N, USER_NAME, ACTION, DATAOPER) 
VALUES (N.NEXTVAL, GET_APP_USER, 'INSERT', sysdate);
END IF;
CHANGES.NUM := 0;
END;
```

После компиляции я получаю ошибку:

```
Compilation failed, line 4 (08:53:55) The line numbers associated with compilation errors are relative to the first BEGIN statement. This only affects the compilation of database triggers.
PL/SQL: ORA-00984: column not allowed hereCompilation failed, line 3 (08:53:55) The line numbers associated with compilation errors are relative to the first BEGIN statement. This only affects the compilation of database triggers.
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
```

Comment: А что такое `N`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Немного изменены названия. У меня такой код для отслеживания изменений в первой таблице. Вставляешь в первую, во вторую идёт новое значение (указывает - i). Если обновил или удалил в первой, то во второй появляется старая строка с удалённой или измененной записью. Удобно следить за "любимыми" пользователями :)
В зависимости от таблицы меняй параметры вставки. Если нужно только вставлять новые записи, то оставь только "IF inserting THEN..", а остальное удали..

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER table1_TRG_BIDU
  BEFORE INSERT OR DELETE OR UPDATE ON table1
  FOR EACH ROW    
BEGIN
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  IF inserting THEN
    INSERT INTO table2
     (id, city, fio, post, e_mail, contacts, annotation, is_active, add_date, evn_date, evn_type, app_user, os_user)
     VALUES(
            :NEW.id,
            :NEW.city,
            :NEW.fio,
            :NEW.post,
            :NEW.e_mail,
            :NEW.contacts,
            :NEW.annotation,
            :NEW.is_active,
            :NEW.add_date,
            sysdate,
            'i',
            user,
            substr(sys_context('userenv', 'OS_USER'), 1, 200));
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ELSIF deleting THEN
   INSERT INTO table2
     (id, city, fio, post, e_mail, contacts, annotation, is_active, add_date, evn_date, evn_type, app_user, os_user)
     VALUES(
            :OLD.id,
            :OLD.city,
            :OLD.fio,
            :OLD.post,
            :OLD.e_mail,
            :OLD.contacts,
            :OLD.annotation,
            :OLD.is_active,
            :OLD.add_date,
            sysdate,
            'd',
            user,
            substr(sys_context('userenv', 'OS_USER'), 1, 200));
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ELSIF updating THEN
      INSERT INTO table2
     (id, city, fio, post, e_mail, contacts, annotation, is_active, add_date, evn_date, evn_type, app_user, os_user)
     VALUES(
            :OLD.id,
            :OLD.city,
            :OLD.fio,
            :OLD.post,
            :OLD.e_mail,
            :OLD.contacts,
            :OLD.annotation,
            :OLD.is_active,
            :OLD.add_date,
            sysdate,
            'u',
            null,
            substr(sys_context('userenv', 'OS_USER'), 1, 200));
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  END IF;

  exception
  when others then
    write_log('Ошибка в триггере table1_TRG_BIDU: '||
      sqlerrm||chr(13)||dbms_utility.format_error_backtrace);
END;
```